# Adding different shades to a 3D plot in Python and Matplotlib

Tags: python, graph, matplotlib, plot

I'm looking for a VERY simple way of changing the colour of my 3D plot to make it look more interesting.

Here is my code (had to delete most of it because said i had too much code in my post):

```
from numpy import *
from matplotlib.pyplot import *
from mpl_toolkits.mplot3d import Axes3D
from numpy import array
from matplotlib import pyplot
from math import sqrt    

X, Y = np.mgrid[:9, :21]

fig = figure()
ax = fig.add_subplot(1,1,1, projection='3d')
ax.set_xlabel('Time')
ax.set_ylabel('Step')
ax.set_zlabel('Probability')

ax.plot_surface(X, Y, probs)
show()
```

Here is my graph:

[image: Graph]

Any help would really be appreciated!!

Ive tried using the http://matplotlib.org/mpl_toolkits/mplot3d to no avail

Comment: `plot_surface` takes a `cmap` parameter that you can use to color the surface http://matplotlib.org/examples/mplot3d/surface3d_demo.html

Comment: thanks for the reply! i added the following code: surf = ax.plot_surface(X, Y, Z, rstride=1, cstride=1, cmap=cm.coolwarm, linewidth=0, antialiased=False) fig.colorbar(surf, shrink=0.5, aspect=5) fig = figure() surf.plot_surface(X, Y, probs) show()    now it says ax not defined, which it didnt say before